# NetBeans. Code Completion. PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, code-completion

I use something like this:

```
index.php(entryPoint)

<?php
include 'view.php';
$view= new View;

$view->a=5;
$view->render('index.tpl');
```

---

```
view.php
<?

clas View{    
   public function render($file){     
        include 'templates/'.$file;
   }
}
```

---

```
templates/index.tpl


<?php /* @var $this View */?>
//some html
<?php $this->| ?> /*I want to see "a" incode completion here
                  How it is possible?
```

I know that something like this are allowed in ZendFramework plugin
Maybe I can add it with my framework?
   some other html */

UPD:
I want to see properties which I used in `index.php` in code completion in `index.tpl`
Properties should not be listed in `view php` as properties

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked. Please re-phrase into a question instead of a statement.

Comment: I think he's asking if he can have code completion recognize the $this as belonging to the View class, and open up the list of completion options when he starts typing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work:

```
<?php /* @var $this Viewer */?>
```

And there are a few reasons for that. First, docblocks start with `/**` not just `/*` . Also you declare `$this` to be an instance of `Viewer`, but the actual class name is `View`. That doesn't match, so you won't get any code completion (or at least not the expected code completion).
So you should use:

```
<?php /** @var $this View */?>
```

Also, if you want access to properties, you should declare them. That's the only way Netbeans will know about the properties.

I have not tested if specifying a class for `$this` in a docblock will actually work.

Comment: But /* works too.(I see method of View just now) But my question was: can I view properties which I use in a.php and not declare in view.php see in my template

Comment: You can't, because Netbeans can't detect which properties exist if you do not declare them.

Comment: But For example in plugin for ZendFramework(I think in plugins for Symphony too) it is possible to use those properties of view in viewer template, which used in thispage controller. I understand that it is not allowed for me in default NetBeans but maybe I can  extend it somehow?

Comment: I don't know whether or not code completion in views is working with ZF or Symphony (I don't use either), so I don't know how it would work there.